# How to filter a dataframe by a nested list in R?

Tags: r, list, filter

I have a dataframe that I need to filter by a nested list, like what I have below. My actual nested list has about 12 lists inside.

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 233 |
| 2 | 234 |
| 3 | 235 |
| 4 | 125 |
| 5 | 188 |
| 6 | 189 |
| 7 | 101 |
| 8 | 23 |

```
listA -> list(233,234,235)
listB -> list(188,189)

listC -> list(listA,listB)

df2 -> df1 %>%
   filter(ColumnB %in% listC)
```

I have previously used %in% to filter results by an unnested list, but this method does not seem to work for nested lists. Is there a way to do this without having to filter by each list individually?

Comment: You should use `<-`, not `->`

Comment: `df1 %>% 
  filter(ColumnB %in% unlist(listC))`